# Effects of hidden groups and multisite mailing

Tags: groups, mailing

I'm looking for some clarity on hidden groups. We have 50 states using a multisite instance and the mailer doesn't work well with multisite.

To achieve segmentation, it seems like creating mailings through search is the only way to do it. If we did that, and each state sent 4 mailings per month. We are at 200 hidden groups each mo and 2400 after 1 year.

Is there harm in this or would a process to delete the hidden groups be satisfactory?

Or should an entire new mailer be developed to make multisite mail more intelligently? For instance, it should look at 1 group we have setup (e.g. Volunteers) and then have an AND clause of the users ACL to limit the contacts to their area, be it state or county.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My test so far following [artfulrobot's advice](https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/qmao1xuxniyupypyadouzj6a5o) was that deleting a hidden group did not effect the normal mailing functionality (unsubscribe/optout/click/open tracking/reports).